# Copy non-merged cells from one worksheet to merged cells in another using a loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, merge

I have done a lot of both trying and failing and searching the internet for a solution, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to solve my problem. Now I hope you guys can help me out.

I am trying to copy a range of cells (non-merged) from one worksheet (ws) to another range which contains merged cells in another worksheet (omk). I have to do this for 20 ranges or so, so I am using a loop. The code I have written so far is pasted below:

```
Dim omk, ws As Worksheet
Dim a, b, i, y, z As Integer
Dim x As Range

Set omk = Sheets("Omkostningsmodel")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

omk.Activate

a = 173
i = 187
For Each cell In Range("C187", "C206")
    z = 3
    b = 3
    For Each x In Range(Cells(i, z), Cells(i, 22))
        x.Value = ws.Cells(a, b)
        z = z + 1
        b = b + 1
        If z = 4 Or z = 13 Or z = 16 Then
            z = z + 1
        End If
    Next x
    a = a + 1
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

My problem is that column c and d (3 and 4) is merged in the worksheet "omk", and therefore I have tried to make the second loop skip column d, while keeping column d in worksheet "ws" "locked" when this happens. However when I run the code, it seems like column d in worksheet "ws" isn't locked?

I am not sure, I have been clear enough, so please let me know if you can't follow my problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the offset method to fill the value in the next column when you have a merged column. Something like:

```
Dim omk as Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim a as Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer
Dim y As Integer, z As Integer, Coloffset As Integer
Dim x As Range, cell As Range

Set omk = Sheets("Omkostningsmodel")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

omk.Activate

a = 173
i = 187

For Each cell In Range("C187", "C206")
    z = 3
    b = 3
    Coloffset = 0
    For Each x In Range(Cells(i, z), Cells(i, 22))
        If x.Column = 4 Or x.Column = 13 Or x.Column = 16 Then
            Coloffset = Coloffset + 1
        End If

        x.Offset(0, Coloffset).Value = ws.Cells(a, b)

        b = b + 1
    Next x
    a = a + 1
    i = i + 1
Next cell
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost managed to figure it out myself before I read your response, but your answer helped me solve the rest :D

Comment: Glad I could help.